# RGB to HSV conversion using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-space

I'm trying to automate the enhancement of some images that are to be transfered to a digital frame. I have code in place that resizes, adds a date/time to the least-significant (least details) corner of the image and pastes together pairs of portrait images to avoid displaying a single portrait in the frame's 41:20 low resolution screen.

I've implemented a brightness-stretching filter for those pictures where the lighting wasn't so good, using the [`colorsys.rgb_to_hsv`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html) function to calculate H, S, V bands, operating on the V one and then converting back to RGB before saving a JPEG in the digital frame. Obviously, the conversion takes a lot of time, even using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) tricks; I managed to improve things using [`psyco`](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/).

However, I noticed an example for the PIL [`Image.convert`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) where RGB can be converted to [XYZ color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_colour_space) using a 4×4 matrix as a second argument to the `convert` method, and I got to wonder:

How can I convert RGB to HSV (and then HSV back to RGB) using a custom matrix in the `convert` method call? (Minor rounding errors are not important in this case, so I don't mind that each band will be expressed as a series of 0…255 integers)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: NB: it is possible that what I do can also be done by the `ImageOps.autocontrast` function; however, I want to be able to expand the filter as needed (e.g. maybe spice up the saturation a little), and that is why I want a quick method for RGB↔HSV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've seen references[1] that claim HSV color-space is linear transformation from RGB, which would seem to imply that it could be done with a matrix, I have been unable to find or determine for myself just what such a matrix would look like. In a way this doesn't really surprise me based on all the [similar] non-matrix procedural implementations I've also seen -- the way they go about it doesn't *look* linear.

Anyway, while looking into this, I ran across a [somewhat dated] article in former SGI researcher [Paul Haeberli](http://www.graficaobscura.com/paul/index.html)'s online computer graphics notebook titled [*Matrix Operations for Image Processing*](http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html) which describes how to do a number of different color transformations using 4x4 matrices which might help you. All of the examples given operate directly on RGB color images and, like geometric matrix transformations, any sequence of them can be combined into a single matrix using concatenation.

Hope this helps.

---

[1]: *Colour Space Conversions* <http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/coloureq.pdf>:

> 2.7.3 HSL (Hue Saturation and Lightness)
>
> This represents a wealth of similar
>   colour spaces, alternative names 
>   include HSI (intensity), HSV (value),
>   HCI (chroma / colourfulness), HVC, 
>   TSD (hue saturation and darkness) etc.
>   Most of these colour spaces are 
>   **linear transforms from RGB** and are
>   therefore device dependent and 
>   non–linear. Their advantage lies in
>   the extremely intuitive manner of 
>   specifying colour. It is very easy to
>   select a desired hue and to then 
>   modify it slightly by adjustment of
>   its saturation and intensity.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it. Like you, the code I've seen so far does not make me optimistic about a positive answer to my question…

Comment: Something that came close (but no cigar): [Converting between RGB and…](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/texture_colour/convert/) by Paul Bourke. Unfortunately, the conversion to-and-fro YIQ/YUV skews a lot the color information; perhaps this is due to the few decimal places of the numbers in the matrices. In any case, they are not useful as-is.

Comment: The transformations are indeed linear, but they are piecewise, so I think it is impossible to transform with a single matrix (and I'm not sure it would be much useful or possible to use "piecewise-matrices").

Answer (score 0):

The formula to transform an RGB value to an HSV value can be found here: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm. I once needed it the other way around, and made the following function for it.

```
def hsb2rgb(hsb):
    '''
    Transforms a hsb array to the corresponding rgb tuple
    In: hsb = array of three ints (h between 0 and 360, s and v between 0 and 100)
    Out: rgb = array of three ints (between 0 and 255)
    '''
    H = float(hsb[0] / 360.0)
    S = float(hsb[1] / 100.0)
    B = float(hsb[2] / 100.0)

    if (S == 0):
        R = int(round(B * 255))
        G = int(round(B * 255))
        B = int(round(B * 255))
    else:
        var_h = H * 6
        if (var_h == 6):
            var_h = 0  # H must be < 1
        var_i = int(var_h)
        var_1 = B * (1 - S)
        var_2 = B * (1 - S * (var_h - var_i))
        var_3 = B * (1 - S * (1 - (var_h - var_i)))

        if      (var_i == 0):
            var_r = B     ; var_g = var_3 ; var_b = var_1
        elif (var_i == 1):
            var_r = var_2 ; var_g = B     ; var_b = var_1
        elif (var_i == 2):
            var_r = var_1 ; var_g = B     ; var_b = var_3
        elif (var_i == 3):
            var_r = var_1 ; var_g = var_2 ; var_b = B
        elif (var_i == 4):
            var_r = var_3 ; var_g = var_1 ; var_b = B
        else:
            var_r = B     ; var_g = var_1 ; var_b = var_2

        R = int(round(var_r * 255))
        G = int(round(var_g * 255))
        B = int(round(var_b * 255))

    return [R, G, B]
```

Comment: I already use the `colorsys` module. The question asked about a matrix that can be used with the `convert` function.