# Change saturation with Imagekit, PIL or Pillow?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, imagekit, django-imagekit

How do I go about changing the saturation of an image using PIL or Pillow? Preferably I'd like to be able to use the solution together with the django-imagekit package. The reason I need to change the saturation is to create an effect where when the user hovers a black-and-white image it turns to colored.

Comment: Pillow **is** PIL, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using django-imagekit, you can just use the bundled `Adjust` processor:

```
from imagekit.processors import Adjust
Adjust(color=0.5)
```

Under the hood, this will do exactly what [@abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070078/change-saturation-with-pil-or-pillow#answer-16070333).

Comment: Thanks @matthewwithanm. This is exactly what I was looking for. I think I ended up creating my own processor back then, which was a good practice but I was pretty sure it must be in imagekit somewhere.

Answer (score 32):

You probably want [`ImageEnhance.Color`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html#PIL.ImageEnhance.Color).

```
img = PIL.Image.open('bus.png')
converter = PIL.ImageEnhance.Color(img)
img2 = converter.enhance(0.5)
```

This gives an image with half the "color" of the original. This isn't exactly the same thing as half the saturation (because half or double the saturation would usually underflow or overflow), but it's probably what you actually *want* most of the time. As the docs say, it works like the "color" knob on a TV.

Here's an example of the same image at 0.5, 1.0, and 2.0 color:
[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want a greyscale image, simply convert it to the `L` (Luminance) mode:

```
greyscale = rgba_image.convert('L')
```

Applying that to my ninja:

[image: cute ninja] [image: greyscale cute ninja]

If you need intermediary steps, you need to convert the RGB value to HLS or HSV, adjust the saturation, then convert it back to RGB again. You could use [colorsys](http://effbot.org/librarybook/colorsys.htm) for that, or adapt [this `numpy` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890373/detecting-thresholds-in-hsv-color-space-from-rgb-using-python-pil/4890878#4890878); I would expect the latter to perform better.

Comment: Or make a luminance-mode version and blend it with the original.