# Numpy dot product

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, rgb, yuv

I have an image represented with a Numpy array, i.e. each pixel is an array [r,g,b].
Now, I want to convert it in YUV using matrix multiplication and trying not to use loops.

```
self.yuv=self.rgb
self.yuv=dot([[   0.299,  0.587,    0.114  ],
              [-0.14713, -0.28886,  0.436  ],
              [   0.615, -0.51499, -0.10001]], 
             self.yuv[:,:])
```

I get the error - objects not aligned. I guess that's because self.yuv[i,j] is not a vertical vector. transpose doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't rgb a 3 dimensional array. Can you tell us what gives `self.rgb.ndim`?

Comment: So, you shouldn't use `self.yuv[:,:]`. Here's a good answer for HSV conversion. You may like to check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890373/detecting-thresholds-in-hsv-color-space-from-rgb-using-python-pil/4890878#4890878

Comment: What is `self.rgb.shape`? `(X,Y,3)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your matrix has shape `(3, 3)` while your image has shape `(rows, cols, 3)` and `np.dot` does "a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b."

The simplest solution is to reverse the order of the operands inside `np.dot` and transpose your conversion matrix:

```
rgb2yuv = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                    [-0.14713, -0.28886, 0.436],
                    [0.615, -0.51499, -0.10001]])
self.yuv = np.dot(self.rgb, rgb2yuv.T)
```