# batch pairwise dot product using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, dot-product

I have two batches of vectors :
W= [w1,w2, w3,...]

and

V= [v1,v2,v3,...].

Both batches are expressed in numpy 2D vectors [[x1, y1], [x2,y2]...]

I want to calculate the pairwise dot product between any element in W  and a element in V, and i want a matrix of  possible combinations, i.e

[ w1.v1 , w1.v2 , w1.v3,...

w2.v1 , w2.v2 , w2.v3,...

w3.v1 , w3.v2 , w3.v3,...

....................................... ]

if w and v are simple scalars then this is easy.

But the problem is w and v are 1D vectors : [x, y]

How do I implement this in numpy?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy dot product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798771/numpy-dot-product)

Comment: This looks like plain matrix multiplication to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to compute the dot products of row vectors,

```
np.einsum('ji,ki-> jk', V, W)
```

If column vectors

```
np.einsum('ij,ik-> jk', V, W)
```

Comment: hello, im a noob at Einstein Summation. What do you mean by column and row vectors?

Comment: @AbelTan you have an array [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]] and another [[x, y, z], [w, s, t]] Is your result a 3x3 array (so you take the dot products of the columns of the original arrays( or 2x2 (so you take dot products of rows)? In the latter case, the first recipe works, in the former, the second.

Comment: its a 3x3 array, so i take the second recipe?