# Changing image hue with Python PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, hue

Using Python PIL, I'm trying to adjust the hue of a given image.

I'm not very comfortable with the jargon of graphics, so what I mean by “adjusting hue” is doing the Photoshop operation called [“Hue/saturation”](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/pics/apps/photoshop/usage/colours/huesaturation/900.png): this is to change the color of the image uniformly as shown below:

- Original: [image: Original]
- With hue adjusted to +180 (red): [image: hue: -180]
- With hue adjusted to -78 (green): [image: hue: -78]

FYI, Photoshop uses a scale of -180 to +180 for this hue setting (where -180 equals +180), that may represents the [HSL hue scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Hue_and_chroma) (expressed in 0-360 degree).

What I'm looking for is **a function that, given an PIL image and a float *hue* within [0, 1] (or int within [0, 360], it doesn't matter), returns the image with its hue shifted by *hue*** as in the example above.

What I've done so far is ridiculous and obviously doesn't give the desired result. It just half-blend my original image with a color-filled layer.

```
import Image

im = Image.open('tweeter.png')
layer = Image.new('RGB', im.size, 'red') # "hue" selection is done by choosing a color...
output = Image.blend(im, layer, 0.5)
output.save('output.png', 'PNG')
```

(Please-don't-laugh-at-) result: [image: output.png]

Thanks in advance!

---

**Solution**: here is the unutbu code updated so it fits exactly what I've described.

```
import Image
import numpy as np
import colorsys

rgb_to_hsv = np.vectorize(colorsys.rgb_to_hsv)
hsv_to_rgb = np.vectorize(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb)

def shift_hue(arr, hout):
    r, g, b, a = np.rollaxis(arr, axis=-1)
    h, s, v = rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
    h = hout
    r, g, b = hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
    arr = np.dstack((r, g, b, a))
    return arr

def colorize(image, hue):
    """
    Colorize PIL image `original` with the given
    `hue` (hue within 0-360); returns another PIL image.
    """
    img = image.convert('RGBA')
    arr = np.array(np.asarray(img).astype('float'))
    new_img = Image.fromarray(shift_hue(arr, hue/360.).astype('uint8'), 'RGBA')

    return new_img
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554627/rgb-to-hsv-conversion-using-pil

Comment: As will this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890373/detecting-thresholds-in-hsv-color-space-from-rgb-using-python-pil

Comment: in colorize(myimage, hueshift), myimage has to be a pil image so a convertion from numpy array to PIl must be performed with: Image.fromarray(myRGBimage) . Great !

Comment: Note that your hue shift function doesn't actually hue shift -- it sets a particular hue (h = hout), meaning your resulting image will be colorized to a single color.

Comment: You can fix the issue @Mala mentioned by replacing
`h = hout`
with
`h = (h + hout) % 1`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is Python code to convert RGB to HSV (and vice versa) in the [colorsys module in the standard library](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/colorsys.py?view=markup). My first attempt used

```
rgb_to_hsv=np.vectorize(colorsys.rgb_to_hsv)
hsv_to_rgb=np.vectorize(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb)
```

to vectorize those functions. Unfortunately, using `np.vectorize` results in rather slow code.

I was able to obtain roughly a 5 times speed up by translating  `colorsys.rgb_to_hsv` and `colorsys.hsv_to_rgb` into native numpy operations.

```
import Image
import numpy as np

def rgb_to_hsv(rgb):
    # Translated from source of colorsys.rgb_to_hsv
    # r,g,b should be a numpy arrays with values between 0 and 255
    # rgb_to_hsv returns an array of floats between 0.0 and 1.0.
    rgb = rgb.astype('float')
    hsv = np.zeros_like(rgb)
    # in case an RGBA array was passed, just copy the A channel
    hsv[..., 3:] = rgb[..., 3:]
    r, g, b = rgb[..., 0], rgb[..., 1], rgb[..., 2]
    maxc = np.max(rgb[..., :3], axis=-1)
    minc = np.min(rgb[..., :3], axis=-1)
    hsv[..., 2] = maxc
    mask = maxc != minc
    hsv[mask, 1] = (maxc - minc)[mask] / maxc[mask]
    rc = np.zeros_like(r)
    gc = np.zeros_like(g)
    bc = np.zeros_like(b)
    rc[mask] = (maxc - r)[mask] / (maxc - minc)[mask]
    gc[mask] = (maxc - g)[mask] / (maxc - minc)[mask]
    bc[mask] = (maxc - b)[mask] / (maxc - minc)[mask]
    hsv[..., 0] = np.select(
        [r == maxc, g == maxc], [bc - gc, 2.0 + rc - bc], default=4.0 + gc - rc)
    hsv[..., 0] = (hsv[..., 0] / 6.0) % 1.0
    return hsv

def hsv_to_rgb(hsv):
    # Translated from source of colorsys.hsv_to_rgb
    # h,s should be a numpy arrays with values between 0.0 and 1.0
    # v should be a numpy array with values between 0.0 and 255.0
    # hsv_to_rgb returns an array of uints between 0 and 255.
    rgb = np.empty_like(hsv)
    rgb[..., 3:] = hsv[..., 3:]
    h, s, v = hsv[..., 0], hsv[..., 1], hsv[..., 2]
    i = (h * 6.0).astype('uint8')
    f = (h * 6.0) - i
    p = v * (1.0 - s)
    q = v * (1.0 - s * f)
    t = v * (1.0 - s * (1.0 - f))
    i = i % 6
    conditions = [s == 0.0, i == 1, i == 2, i == 3, i == 4, i == 5]
    rgb[..., 0] = np.select(conditions, [v, q, p, p, t, v], default=v)
    rgb[..., 1] = np.select(conditions, [v, v, v, q, p, p], default=t)
    rgb[..., 2] = np.select(conditions, [v, p, t, v, v, q], default=p)
    return rgb.astype('uint8')


def shift_hue(arr,hout):
    hsv=rgb_to_hsv(arr)
    hsv[...,0]=hout
    rgb=hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
    return rgb

img = Image.open('tweeter.png').convert('RGBA')
arr = np.array(img)

if __name__=='__main__':
    green_hue = (180-78)/360.0
    red_hue = (180-180)/360.0

    new_img = Image.fromarray(shift_hue(arr,red_hue), 'RGBA')
    new_img.save('tweeter_red.png')

    new_img = Image.fromarray(shift_hue(arr,green_hue), 'RGBA')
    new_img.save('tweeter_green.png')
```

yields

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: So it indeed requires some numpy array manipulation… I thought it would have required less operations but, well, it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: As you convert the image to RGB right from the beginning, I believe there is no transparency support there. Nevertheless, I think a simple alpha extraction before the operations, followed by a putalpha() on the final result should do the trick!

Comment: @Zopieux: I changed the code to handle RGBA, so no `putalpha` is necessary.

Comment: Isn't there a bug in there: The current way the maximum in `rgb_to_hsv` is computed, using the slice `rgb[...,:2]` only the R and G channel are considered. It should probably be `rgb[...,:3]`

Comment: Beware that you aren't exactly implementing the colorsys algorithm. for R=255, G=255 and B=0. colorsys returns : [0.16666666666666666, 1, 255], where yours returns : [  0.83333333   1.         255.        ] . For rotate hue it's not a problem but when using these function to do stuffs like chroma keying   with another lib that use HSV it can create some problems (it can even drive someone crazy :/ ). I'm still wondering if its a bug or no.

Comment: WHEN R=  255  G=  0  B=  0
colorsys returns :  (0.0, 1, 255)
your alg returns :  (0.0, 1.0, 255.0)


WHEN R=  255  G=  255  B=  0
colorsys returns :  (0.1666, 1, 255)
your alg returns :  (0.8333, 1.0, 255.0)


it seems simply inverted. 

WHEN R=  0  G=  255  B=  0
colorsys returns :  (0.3333, 1, 255)
your alg returns :  (0.6666, 1.0, 255.0)


WHEN R=  0  G=  255  B=  255
colorsys returns :  (0.5, 1, 255)
your alg returns :  (0.5, 1.0, 255.0)


WHEN R=  0  G=  0  B=  255
colorsys returns :  (0.6666, 1, 255)
your alg returns :  (0.3333, 1.0, 255.0)

Comment: @snoobdogg: I believe my implementation of `rgb_to_hsv` is correct: `rgb_to_hsv(np.array([[[255,0,0],[255,255,0],[0,255,0],[0,255,255],[0,0,255]]]))` yields `array([[[0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 2.55000000e+02],
        [1.66666667e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 2.55000000e+02],
        [3.33333333e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 2.55000000e+02],
        [5.00000000e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 2.55000000e+02],
        [6.66666667e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 2.55000000e+02]]])` which agrees with `colorsys.rgb_to_hsv`.

Answer (score 18):

With a recent copy of Pillow, one should probably use [Image.convert()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert):

```
def rgb2hsv(image: PIL.Image.Image):
    return image.convert('HSV')
```

Comment: It seems that during the conversion process, internally it attempts to "write" bytes to a buffer, which results in:
OSError: cannot write mode HSV as PNG

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  PIL does not convert to to a HSV or HSL colorspace, but this is the conversion you need to do in order to alter the hue without any changes to the lightness and saturation of the image.

What you need to do is convert to HSV, then increment all the H values by some degree, then convert back to RGB.

Half the work is done for you in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890373/detecting-thresholds-in-hsv-color-space-from-rgb-using-python-pil/4890878#4890878) (by me) some time ago.  It employs another python module called NumPy and converts RGB colorspace to HSV.  It would not be too much trouble to write the reverse conversion.