# python PIL : shift the hue and saturation

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, hue

From GIMP, I can shift the hue and saturation easily. For example, below are the original picture and the final results after set hue to -90 and saturation to 100.

How can I proceed to get the same results from Python PIL?

## Original Picture

[image: original picture]

## Final Picture

[image: final picture]

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274221/changing-image-hue-with-python-pil

Comment: It's not same. What I want is to rotate the hue .

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a combination of the `colorsys` module and `PIL`, but it's kind of slow. `colorsys` allows you to change the color space to HSV where it's trivial to do hue and saturation modifications. I take the saturation to the power of 0.65 to approximate your example, it retains the range of 0.0-1.0 needed by `colorsys` while increasing the middle values.

```
import colorsys
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(filename)
ld = im.load()
width, height = im.size
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        r,g,b = ld[x,y]
        h,s,v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255., g/255., b/255.)
        h = (h + -90.0/360.0) % 1.0
        s = s**0.65
        r,g,b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
        ld[x,y] = (int(r * 255.9999), int(g * 255.9999), int(b * 255.9999))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems perfect! Thanks! I will try it and continue my brown detection !

Comment: It works! But yes, it's a bit slow. I wonder how it can be faster

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend converting your image into a [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array, and then applying the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) rgb_to_hsv function:  http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv  That way you can avoid the double for loop which is probably causing the pixel-by-pixel method using colorsys to be slow.